# Changing the colour of a link with "text-decoration:none;" property

Tags: html, css

How can I change the colour of a link that has "text-decoration:none;" property?

I have already tried placing it in a span element as it was suggested but it didn't work.

```
<html>
    <style>
        a:link {
            text-decoration:none;   /* unvisited link */
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <a href="https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lq8gU_yiAcHj_Abj1oCoDg">google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a:link{color:inherit}
a:active{color:inherit}
a:visited{color:inherit}
a:hover{color:inherit}

Comment: Inherit means: "get the color of the link from the parent element"

Comment: the point in using the text decoration is to get rid of the underline... how can i get rid of it in any other way?

Comment: remove :link, you don't need that

Comment: what do you mean? I do need it as a link...

Comment: @Shiran I don't understand what the problem is.  This should work.

Comment: the problem is that I can't get rid of the irritating underline and at the same time change the colour..

Comment: What browser are you using?  It works for me in Chrome.

Comment: is this your expected output? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QnEc9/1/)

Comment: @Shiran It works for me in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aEjL8/  Maybe you visited the link previously?

Comment: @Shiran have you checked the fiddle of mine??

Comment: @Anonymous it doesn't work as it is.. I had to remove the ":link"

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't seem to accomplish what you wanted since it targets **all** links instead of just those that were not previously visited.